# Powershell FTP Script String Concatenation

Tags: powershell, ftp

My Powershell script works fine this way (it uses FTP to send `IHM_OTP_CRT_20190812_0701.txt` to the server and save it as `newfile.txt`)

```
$File = "Z:\Export\IHM_OTP_CRT_20190812_0701.txt"

$ftp = "ftp://ftpuse:mypass@e2b.kpsci.com/inbound/newfile.txt"

"ftp url: $ftp"

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)

"Uploading $File..."

$webclient.UploadFile($uri, $File)
```

But it does not work if I change the second line

```
$ftp = "ftp://ftpuse:mypass@e2b.kpsci.com/inbound/newfile.txt"
```

to the following

```
$File = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'IHM_OTP_CRT_.' } | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1
$NewFileName = $File.Name
$ftp = "ftp://ftpuse:mypass@e2b.kpsci.com/inbound/" + $NewFileName
```

and this is driving me crazy.

I've tried various concatenation methods...I used the ``` $var1``$var2 ``` concept saved into `$NewFileName` to avoid the **+** sign, I've used parenthesis around the argument like:

```
$ftp = ("ftp://ftpuse:mypass@e2b.kpsci.com/inbound/" + $NewFileName)
```

And the more frustrating part is that when I use `@echo`, the concatenated string looks perfect. Also, this works fine:

```
$ftp = "ftp://ftpuse:mypass@e2b.kpsci.com/inbound/" + "IHM_OTP_CRT_20190812_0701.txt"
```

So, it's only concatenating with a separate object (even if it's a string) that doesn't work.  I can concatenate to "blah" but not to a variable that equates to "blah". I've spent hours on this and I don't imagine it should be this difficult.

The error I am receiving is:

```
"Exception calling "UploadFile" with 2 argument(s): "The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command...at :17 char: 22..."
```

The error makes sense to me - it think's that my "concatenated" object contains a separate argument into the Upload File method, but I can't understand how to make it understand that I'm intending to pass a single string.

Comment: step thru your code in ISE or VSCode, and when you get to your problem line, you can see variables and what's happening, and the answer will prob be obvious.

Comment: I tried that - my "Echo" statements were all working fine, but the final FTP did not work.

Comment: ....but then I changed around some code, and at this point I want to check my regex.  I want to find the most recent version of a file starting with "IHM_OTP_CRT_" although there will be dates appended to the end. Because I'm confident the file is not even populated now, even though I know it was earlier... :)

Comment: Silly question, but the working example is different than what are your other examples are doing. Are you trying to set the *destination* ftp path to `$ftp = "ftp....inbound/IHM_OTP_CRT_20190812_0701.txt"` or `$ftp = "ftp....inbound/newfile.txt"`?

Comment: The destination path should be $ftp = "ftp....inbound/IHM_OTP_CRT_20190812_0701.txt"

Comment: Oh, shoot. I think my file exists in a different directory than the one I'm getting child items from in the first line. I want to find the most recently added file starting with IHM_OTP_CRT_, but in a different filepath location.

Comment: (I think I have an idea of what's going on, so just clarifying) so when you tried with working code with the proper path, (e.g destination with a string literal: `$ftp = "ftp....inbound/IHM_OTP_CRT_20190812_0701.txt"`) it worked? i.e. I want to make sure it isn't an issue with the FTP not being able to handle the Underscore characters.

Comment: Yes - to clarify (since I know I updated my post a few times), it definintely worked with "ftp....inbound/IHM_OTP_CRT_20190812_0701.txt" like you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `Get-ChildItem` object `.ToString()` will only return the file name, not the full path. Therefore in the Webclient Upload you have to specify the `.FullName` property:

```
$webclient.UploadFile($uri, $File.FullName)
```

Full code:

```
$File = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'IHM_OTP_CRT_.' } | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1
$NewFileName = $File.Name
$ftp = "ftp://ftpuse:mypass@e2b.kpsci.com/inbound/" + $NewFileName 

"ftp url: $ftp"

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)

"Uploading $File..."

$webclient.UploadFile($uri, $File.FullName)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you!! I was focusing too much on the $ftp variable, but I needed to pass the FULL file path into "UploadFile" since my file is stored in a different location than where my script is running...while appending the short file name to /inbound. It's funny because it took me another day after a full night's sleep to even realize that your response was exactly what I needed.